# Java - creating Array of JPanel makes null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, jpanel

I'm trying to make an array of `jpanels` but I got some `null pointer exception`.

here is the part of the code. The `cartP` here is a `panel`.

```
JPanel[] p2 = new JPanel[10];
    p2[0].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 40));
    p2[0].setMaximumSize(p2[0].getPreferredSize());
    p2[0].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5,1,1));
    p2[0].add(new JLabel("text"));
    p2[0].add(new JLabel("text"));
    p2[0].add(new JLabel("text"));
    p2[0].add(new JLabel("text"));
    p2[0].setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    cartP.add(p2[0]);
```

I'll use it for making a view cart just like on the shopping website.

here is the exception..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at storeapp.Cart.gui(Cart.java:59)
at storeapp.Cart.<init>(Cart.java:29)
at storeapp.Cart.main(Cart.java:157)
```

Java Result: 1

Any idea why i get that exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize each JPanel with something like this::

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   p2[i] = new JPanel();
}
```

Array of objects and array of primitive types behave in different ways.

Although elements of array types like `int` and `float` are not required to be created on the heap with `new`, you must initialize arrays of objects.

`JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[10]` creates 10 UNINITIALIZED objects for JPanel(or just initializes the array). Since they're not initialized, you will have to call `new` on each JPanel to initialize them separately.

Comment: _"...creates 10 UNINITIALIZED objects"_ is a misleading sentence. There is no such thing as an "uninitialized object," only variables and references which have not been initialized. It is also misleading/incorrect to say _"call `new` on [a] JPanel."_ You are not calling a method, nor applying an operator to, an existing object.

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
JPanel[] p2 = new JPanel[10];
```

creates an array of `null` `JPanel` pointers. You need to initialize each element of the array before using it.

```
for (int i=0; i<p2.length; i++) {
    p2[i] = new JPanel(/* snip */);
}
```

This is consistent with the behavior for *any* array initialization. Until otherwise assigned, elements of an array have the array type's default value; [for *any* object type, the default value is `null`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#h1).

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel[] p2 = new JPanel[10];

for (int i = 0; i < p2.length; i++){
    p2[i] = new JPanel();
}
```

....

your code

Comment: You can add some information also. Why and where to do those changes?